# Weird keyboard bug

Tags: 14.04, keyboard

I use ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell XPS 15. My keyboard is not working properly. Let me try to describe what the problem is. 
It happens only with the keys asdfghjkl; When I press them, their behaviour is, in one word, unpredictable. Sometimes they work normally, other times, I have to hold them down and the letter comes up after a delay which varies. Also, when we hold the key, there should be a pause before the second letter occurs, but the pause sometimes doesn't work here. I endd up typing likkke thisss.
It doesn't seem like a hardware bug. I believe it is related to an update I did a few days ago(The update came in a popup box and I installed it without a second thought). I am really confused as to what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First verify is this behaviour exists in console mode (**Ctrl-Alt-F1**). *It still sounds like a hardware issue.*

Comment: The behaviour does exist in console mode. Does that make it a harware issue? Also, I cleaned the keyboard for dust by removing the keys shorty before posting the question.

Comment: The test points to either hardware or low-level firmware. *If console had shown different behaviour, it would have pointed to an application or library code.* For this to still be software (or firmware) would be highly unusual. I still think it is hardware. **If you have a spare drive, you could (swap out and) do a fresh install and prove conclusively.**

Comment: You might want to boot from a live usb/cd to rule out software.

Comment: Nice idea, Scott Goodgame. I booted to Ubuntu 12.04(to rule out the possibility of problems with my copy of Ubuntu) from a live USB and the problem persisted. So, david6 is right. I will have a technician look into my keyboard. Thanks a lot, guys.